# Php json insert to mysql data and insert control limits

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach, insert

Hey this script working perfect when in json 8 or more `youtube#video` but when it's lower then 8 like 6 i get error. i need output get insert from 0-8 not only 8.

```
$loop = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT channelid FROM users ORDER BY id") or die (mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop)) {
    $channelid = $row['channelid'];
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelid .'&maxResults=10&key=KEY';
    $content = file_get_contents($url); 
    $json = json_decode($content, true);    

    if(!isset($json['items'])) continue; //skip if no items

    $videos = ['videoId'=>'','videoId1'=>'','videoId2'=>'','videoId3'=>'','videoId4'=>'','videoId5'=>'','videoId6'=>'','videoId7'=>''];
    $videossw = ['vidname'=>'','vidname1'=>'','vidname2'=>'','vidname3'=>'','vidname4'=>'','vidname5'=>'','vidname6'=>'','vidname7'=>''];
    $videoss = ['publishedAt'=>'','publishedAt1'=>''];

    $i = 0;
    //if(isset($videoList[$i]["id"]["videoId"])) {
    foreach($json['items'] as $items) {
        if ($items['id']['kind'] != 'youtube#playlist') {
            $keyy  = 0==$i ? 'publishedAt' : 'publishedAt'.$i;
            $videoss[$keyy] = $items['snippet']['publishedAt'];

            $keyyy  = 0==$i ? 'vidname' : 'vidname'.$i;
            $videossw[$keyyy] = $items['snippet']['title']; 

            $key  = 0==$i ? 'videoId' : 'videoId'.$i;
            $videos[$key] = $items['id']['videoId']; 
            ++$i;
        }
    }
    $qqq = 'INSERT INTO users(channelid, publishedAt, publishedAt1, videoId, videoId1, videoId2, videoId3, videoId4, videoId5, videoId6, videoId7, vidname, vidname1, vidname2, vidname3, vidname4, vidname5, vidname6, vidname7) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channelid=?, publishedAt=?, publishedAt1=?, videoId=?, videoId1=?, videoId2=?, videoId3=?, videoId4=?, videoId5=?, videoId6=?, videoId7=?, vidname=?, vidname1=?, vidname2=?, vidname3=?, vidname4=?, vidname5=?, vidname6=?, vidname7=?';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($qqq);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $channelid, $videoss['publishedAt'], $videoss['publishedAt1'], $videos['videoId'], $videos['videoId1'], $videos['videoId2'], $videos['videoId3'], $videos['videoId4'], $videos['videoId5'], $videos['videoId6'], $videos['videoId7'], $videossw['vidname'], $videossw['vidname1'], $videossw['vidname2'], $videossw['vidname3'], $videossw['vidname4'], $videossw['vidname5'], $videossw['vidname6'], $videossw['vidname7'], $channelid, $videoss['publishedAt'], $videoss['publishedAt1'], $videos['videoId'], $videos['videoId1'], $videos['videoId2'], $videos['videoId3'], $videos['videoId4'], $videos['videoId5'], $videos['videoId6'], $videos['videoId7'], $videossw['vidname'], $videossw['vidname1'], $videossw['vidname2'], $videossw['vidname3'], $videossw['vidname4'], $videossw['vidname5'], $videossw['vidname6'], $videossw['vidname7']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

var_dump

```
array(2) {
  ["kind"]=>
  string(13) "youtube#video"
  ["videoId"]=>
  string(11) "ElNBG63UQ0g"
}
array(2) {
  ["kind"]=>
  string(13) "youtube#video"
  ["videoId"]=>
  string(11) "e3PlqifTrS0"
}
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: videoId in <b>/index.php</b> on line <b>63</b><br />
array(2) {
  ["kind"]=>
  string(15) "youtube#channel"
  ["channelId"]=>
  string(24) "UCynfZM0Edr9cA4pDymb2rEA"
}
```

ON LINE `$videos[$key] = $items['id']['videoId'];`

I get error:

> Notice: Undefined index: videoId

Comment: `var_dump($items['id'])` to see what you get

Comment: Updated question with var_bump

Comment: Its because your array not contain this key. You have different keys in loop. You should check if array key exist and then do something.